# Moving x-axis from above to below the graph?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have plotted $y$ and $R_0(s_\infty-1)$, for different values $R_0$. How do I flip the x-axis so it doesn't look messy?

My attempt:

```
Plot[{Log[ x], 1*(x - 1), 1.5*(x - 1), 2*(x - 1), 2.5*(x - 1), 
  3*(x - 1)}, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashing[None]}, {Red, Dashing[None]}, {Black, 
    Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}, {Black, 
    Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {None, "Fraction susceptible"}}, 
 FrameTicks -> All]
```

We should get this:

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide your code! Perhaps `Solve[Log[S\[Infinity]] == 
  R0 (S\[Infinity] \[Minus] 1), S\[Infinity] ]` might be a good staring point.

Comment: I tried that, but how do I plot the solution given?

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code,not the TeX.

Comment: @cvgmt I was showing all details else I get accused of not posting all the details..

Comment: Hi Math, it looks like you have only posted TeX code for the equations of this question. Can you, please, post your wolfram language code that you have been using to try to solve this question? Then it can be reopened, as it currently lacks such necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

**modified(!question changed!)**

equation

```
eq=Log[S\[Infinity]S0] - R0  (S\[Infinity]S0 S0n - 1) == 0
```

now depends on two parameters `R0,S0n=S0/n`  and is solved for `S\[Infinity]S0=S\[Infinity]/S0`

```
sol=Solve[eq,S\[Infinity]S0 ][[1]]
(*{S\[Infinity]S0 -> -(ProductLog[-E^-R0 R0 S0n]/(R0 S0n))}*)

Plot3D[S\[Infinity]S0 /. sol , {S0n, 0, 2}, {R0, 0, 3},MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(S0\), \(n\)]\)", "R0","\!\(\*FractionBox[\(S\[Infinity]\), \(S0\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I made an error in the question. Shall I delete this and post a new one or edit it this one?

Comment: @Math it is usually better to edit the question, in most cases.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann : cant you solve for $y$ as per the question and plot $y$ against $S/N$?

Comment: @Math What is the definition of `S`? Probably `S\[Infinity]`. Your equation depends on three parameters `S0,N,R0`, though you would need a 4D-Plot!. In my answer I showed a way to visualize `S\[Infinity]/S0=f[R0,S0/N]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann : Definition of $S$ is number of susceptible at time $t$.  I will amend/edit the question again, sorry. We should get the second graph in the question. Let R0 be inputs made by us physically. What I mean is draw the graph of log($s_\infty$) and the graph of $R_0(s_\infty -1)$ for
 different inputs of $R_0$( like $R_0=1, R_0=1.5, R_0=2, R_0=2.5 R_0=3)$. to put things easy, I want you to replicate the second graph after I edit the question.

Comment: What about  parameters S0 and N

Comment: @UlrichNeumann please look at amended question :)

Comment: @Math It is not helpful if you are constantly modifying your question instead of answering my comments. Actually the equation `y==...==0` you asked to solve disappeared

Comment: @UlrichNeumann its still there but I changed it to y=ln($s_\infty)$

Comment: @Math No , your question changed from `Solve y=Log[S\[Infinity]S0] - R0  (S\[Infinity]S0 S0n - 1) == 0 for S\[Infinity] and plot over R0` (which I answered)  to actually `Plot[ {Log[S],Table[R0(S-19,{R0,...}]]m {S,0,1}]`

Comment: I made an error, hence I asked to update the answer. I understand your frustration so no problem. I will try to figure it out..

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I figured it out, but how do I flip the x-axis so that its below the plot so it doesn't look messy?

Comment: Try `AxesOrigin-> {0,-4}`

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: What did you try? `Plot[{Log[S], Table  [R0 (S - 1), {R0, {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3}}]}, {S, 0,
   1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -4}]` creates a plot similar to the picture in your question!

Comment: I put     AxesOrigin-> {0,-4} into my plot, it didn't do anything

Comment: could you try use my code and try putting it down?

Comment: @Math Sorry I'm not a question answer machine. I showed you a working example in the comment. You should check which differences might be seen compared to your attempt. Especially your `Axes->False` gives an idea why AxesOrigin doesn't work...